# How to Debug Javascript in HTML in Webmode.el

Tags: debugging, web-mode, javascript

I am new to Emacs webmode. I was wondering how to debug javascript embedded into my html page using webmode.el. The script is in the `<script>` tag.

I'd like to see break lines and see the values as they progress and have the error shown describing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is a functionality offered by web-mode. What I do for debugging javascript is to just look into the browsers console (most browser do offer one i think, like eg firefox offers one after pressing Ctrl-Shift-J). When he is complaining about my javascript i edit the according line in emacs. For that there is a mode available to support me in this process: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImpatientMode

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer tools provided in your browser and `debugger;` statements in code that you write. Web-mode doesn't provide any functionality for debugging JavaScript.